# How to start the installation of ear on WebSphere?

Tags: websphere, ear

It is required to install the application on the WebSphere via jython using the AdminApp class.
I delete through the method AdminApp.uninstall

```
wsadmin.bat -user alex19 -password qwerty19 -c "AdminApp.uninstall('MK.MyApplicaiton')" -lang jython
```

I want to use the installation method to install the same ear, but I did not succeed using the IBM documentation. Please tell me how to use the wsadmin.bat and AdminApp to install the application?

I get such an error, but the problem is that I do not know how to transfer the file with the properties and the configuration file:

```
C:\WSAS\bin>wsadmin.bat -user alex19 -password qwerty19 -c "AdminApp.install('C:/ear/my-applicaiton.ear')" -lang jython
WASX7209I: Connected to process "adminagent" on node KSDD using SOAP connector;  The type of process is: AdminAgent
WASX7015E: Exception running command: "AdminApp.install('C:/ear/my-applicaiton.ear')"; exception information:
com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException
javax.management.MBeanException
com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException
com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException: ADMA0043E: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\app9157482086909190098.ear does not exist for installation.
```

Comment: Show _something_ you tried from the manual and the error you received? This a site for programming help, not a place to have scripts written for you.

Comment: @covener corrected

Answer (score 0):

> WASX7209I: Connected to process "adminagent"

You ran wsadmin against an admin agent, which cannot run applications. You should install applications to a deployment manager (ND) or an individual application server (base/standalone application servers)